# string manipulation in python to extract specific fields

Tags: python, arrays, string, scripting

I have some data in a file with some user details, a sample line is as follows

```
<User id="123" directoryId="122" userName="vik_username" lowerUserName="vik_username" active="1" createdDate="2013-12-01 08:25:34.451" updatedDate="2014-01-20 19:45:49.133" firstName="Vik" lowerFirstName="vik" lastName="GG" lowerLastName="gg" displayName="Vik GG" lowerDisplayName="vikgg" emailAddress="vikgg@vik.com" lowerEmailAddress="vikgg@vik.com">
```

I want to write a script in python and extract the following fields
1. username -- userName="vik_username"
2. email address -- emailAddress="vikgg@vik.com" 
3. Display name -- displayName="Vik GG"
4. active status -- active="1"

I wrote a python script like this and I am splitting on '" ' a double quote followed by space.

```
f = open("users.txt", "r")
user_array=[]
for x in f:
    y=x.split('" ')
    user_array.append(y)
```

this gives me an array called user_array and it has each user's details as an array.

```
print user_array[0]
```

returns

```
['<User id="123', 'directoryId="122', 'userName="vik_username', 'lowerUserName="vik_username', 'active="1', 'createdDate="2013-12-01 08:25:34.451', 'updatedDate="2014-01-20 19:45:49.133', 'firstName="Vik', 'lowerFirstName="vik', 'lastName="GG', 'lowerLastName="gg', 'displayName="Vik GG', 'lowerDisplayName="vikgg', 'emailAddress="vikgg@vik.com', 'lowerEmailAddress="vikgg@vik.com">\n']
```

Now to get the fields I want
1. username -- userName="vik_username"
2. email address -- emailAddress="vikgg@vik.com" 
3. Display name -- displayName="Vik GG"
4. active status -- active="1"

I would have to do something like
`print(user_array[0][<<index of my field>>])`
 and then split it again to remove the field tag 
for example 
`userName="vik_username`
I will need to remove 
`userName="`

Can someone help me do this in a more efficient manner in python?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data looks like XML or other markup, I'd suggest you to use ready-made parsers such as [lxml](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html). If you add a closing tag to your input string (if it doesn't already exist), you'll be able to interpret it as XML:

```py
from lxml import etree

s = '<User id="123" directoryId="122" userName="vik_username" lowerUserName="vik_username" active="1" createdDate="2013-12-01 08:25:34.451" updatedDate="2014-01-20 19:45:49.133" firstName="Vik" lowerFirstName="vik" lastName="GG" lowerLastName="gg" displayName="Vik GG" lowerDisplayName="vikgg" emailAddress="vikgg@vik.com" lowerEmailAddress="vikgg@vik.com">'
s +='</User>'
myxml = etree.fromstring(s)
d = myxml.attrib

print(d) # Dictionary for further processing
print(d.values()) # The list of values in a dictionary
```

I hope this helps!

#### Edit

Python has also a built-in [`xml`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module with the same functionality:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

s = '<User id="123" directoryId="122" userName="vik_username" lowerUserName="vik_username" active="1" createdDate="2013-12-01 08:25:34.451" updatedDate="2014-01-20 19:45:49.133" firstName="Vik" lowerFirstName="vik" lastName="GG" lowerLastName="gg" displayName="Vik GG" lowerDisplayName="vikgg" emailAddress="vikgg@vik.com" lowerEmailAddress="vikgg@vik.com">'
s +='</User>'
myxml = ET.fromstring(s)
d = myxml.attrib

print(d)
print(d.values())
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use regular expressions:

```
import re

string = r'<User id="123" directoryId="122" userName="vik_username" lowerUserName="vik_username" active="1" createdDate="2013-12-01 08:25:34.451" updatedDate="2014-01-20 19:45:49.133" firstName="Vik" lowerFirstName="vik" lastName="GG" lowerLastName="gg" displayName="Vik GG" lowerDisplayName="vikgg" emailAddress="vikgg@vik.com" lowerEmailAddress="vikgg@vik.com">'
re.findall(r'\"(.*?)\"', string)

>>> ['123', '122', 'vik_username', 'vik_username', '1', '2013-12-01 08:25:34.451', '2014-01-20 19:45:49.133', 'Vik', 'vik', 'GG', 'gg', 'Vik GG', 'vikgg', 'vikgg@vik.com', 'vikgg@vik.com']
```

The expression `\"(.*?)\"` captures (`()`) everything that begins and ends with quotation marks (`\"`) with 0 or more characters in between (`.*?`).

Alternatively, if you don't want to use regex, you could do something like `string.split('\"')[1::2]`, where you split at quotation marks but skip over all the stuff you don't need: the [1::2] bit gets you every second item (::2) starting at the second item in the list (1).

Then you can take whichever items you want from the return values.

---

Quick performance check using Jupyter magic:

```
%timeit -n 100000 string.split('\"')[1::2]
>>> 1.07 µs ± 40.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit -n 100000 re.findall(r'\"(.*?)\"', string)
>>> 4.65 µs ± 30.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

So I'd actually advice you to slice instead of using regex if those microseconds matter to you.

Comment: thanks for the notes about the performance of this, my usecase is to only extra data maybe 2-3 times a day, so performance won't be that much of a challenge in my case, but I wil keep the notes in mind. Thanks for detailed explanation too.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
line = """<User id="123" directoryId="122" userName="vik_username" lowerUserName="vik_username" active="1" createdDate="2013-12-01 08:25:34.451" updatedDate="2014-01-20 19:45:49.133" firstName="Vik" lowerFirstName="vik" lastName="GG" lowerLastName="gg" displayName="Vik GG" lowerDisplayName="vikgg" emailAddress="vikgg@vik.com" lowerEmailAddress="vikgg@vik.com">"""

wanted_tags = ("userName", "emailAddress", "displayName", "active")
tag_contents = [re.search(fr'{tag}="(.*?)"', line).group(1) for tag in wanted_tags]
# ['vik_username', 'vikgg@vik.com', 'Vik GG', '1']
```

We match the given tag and its content via a regex.
You can customize the `wanted_tags` and the resultant list `tag_contents` has the corresponding information to those `wanted_tags`, in order. You can make a dictionary with these 2 if you want.